# How to install a "Code Project" packge/plugin in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: c#, plugins, visual-studio-2015, ftp

I have found the **[FTPFactory](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31624/An-FTP-secure-client-library-for-C)** `Code Project`, and I want to test drive it. However, so far I only installed new packages via Nuget. How do I add `FTPFactory` to my Solution in Visual Studio 2015?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options.

Since this is such a simple single class library, you could just manually copy the ftp.cs file from the source and add it to your project.

Alternately, you can download and build the project which will produce a FTPTest.dll file.  You can add a reference (browse) to this file in your project and use the class form there.